# I'm writing a custom widget for django-admin that requires some JavaScript, where do I put it?

Tags: django, django-admin

It seems wrong to add

```
 <script src="..."></script>
```

to the `render()` of the widget. Especially if I have 2 of them on the same page. Is there a way to add a single script include on the admin form pages, in a way where I don't edit core files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Widgets have a `Media` inner class that allows you to specify scripts and styles that need to be loaded. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/media/).

Comment: That's straight forward and awesome, much better than I expected. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set external javascript libraries in the [Media class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions):

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("my_styles.css",)
        }
        js = ("my_code.js",)
```